# Multiple diff outputs in one patchfile

Tags: unix, diff, versioning, patch

I was trying to store multiple diff outputs in one .patch file to keep versioning in one file instead of running multiple

```
diff -u f1 f2 > f1.patch
```

commands. Preferably I'd keep running

```
diff -u[other params?] f1 f2 >> f1.patch
```

to have one file containing all changes which would allow me to later on run patch on those files to have a f1 file available in any given moment.

Unfortunately patch fails with file generated in such manner. It only seems to apply first patch from the file and then quits with error.

My question: is that possible with *diff* and *patch*? And if so, how?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why are you not just using a full version control system?

Comment: I know i could use git but i'm trying to implement something similar but without the features i don't need.

Comment: Why are you trying to make your life harder than it has to be?

Comment: I only need that one functionality, it's for a project. I can't use git.